# How to combine deb dependencies into main package?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I want to include deb-dependencies with main deb-package.

Consider 1 deb package which have 19 deb dependencies, so I have to install all packages by `dpkg -i *.deb`. If all 19 dependencies can be **combined and created single (master) deb** then I can easily install package by single (1) deb file!

How to do this?

Comment: Already has an answer on the Ask Ubuntu Stack Exchange site: [create final deb file from multiple deb files](//askubuntu.com/a/59096/101406).

Comment: @n.st then post here